# Representation of linear functional for product space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, normed-spaces

Given a real number $p>1$, let $\mathsf{H}^{p}=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{L}^{p}
$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real number and $\mathbb{L}^{p}$ is the
collection of random variables such that $\operatorname{E}(\left\vert
X\right\vert ^{p})<\infty$ for any random variable $X$. $\mathsf{H}^{p}$ is a
linear space equipped with norm

$$
\left\Vert (x,X)\right\Vert =\sqrt{x^{2}+\operatorname{E}(\left\vert
X\right\vert ^{p})^{2/p}}\qquad\qquad(x,X)\in\mathsf{H}^{p}
$$

Is it true that: for every linear functional $f:\mathsf{H}^{p}\rightarrow
\mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique $(y,Y)$ in $\mathsf{H}^{q}=\mathbb{R}
\times\mathbb{L}^{q}$ with $q=\frac{p}{p-1}$ such that
$$
f(x,X)=xy+\operatorname{E}(XY)
$$
for every $(x,X)\in\mathsf{H}^{p}$.

Remark: (Riesz Representation Theorem) For every linear functional $g:\mathbb{L}
^{p}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique $Y$ in $\mathbb{L}^{q}$ with
$q=\frac{p}{p-1}$ such that
$$
g(X)=\operatorname{E}(YX)
$$
for every $X\in\mathbb{L}^{p}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are talking about **continuous** linear functional $f$. The claim is false if $f$ is not continuous.

$X \to f(0,X)$ is a continuous linear functional on $L^{p}$ so $f(0,X)=EXY$ for some $Y \in L^{q}$.
$f(x,0)=xf(1,0)=yx$ where $y=f(1,0)$. Hence, $f(x,X)=f(0,X)+f(x,0)=EXY+xy$.